# define aggfunc for each values column in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Was trying to generate a pivot table with multiple "values" columns. I know I can use aggfunc to aggregate values the way I want to, but what if I don't want to sum or avg both columns but instead I want sum of one column while mean of the other one. So is it possible to do so using pandas?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
          'A' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three'] * 6,
          'B' : ['A', 'B', 'C'] * 8,
          'C' : ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'] * 4,
          'D' : np.random.randn(24),
          'E' : np.random.randn(24)
})
```

Now this will get a pivot table with sum:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D','E'], rows=['B'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

And this for mean:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D','E'], rows=['B'], aggfunc=np.mean)
```

How can I get sum for `D` and mean for `E`?

Hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can **concat two DataFrames**:

```
>>> df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D'], rows=['B'], aggfunc=np.sum)
>>> df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['E'], rows=['B'], aggfunc=np.mean)
>>> pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1)
          D         E
B                    
A  1.810847 -0.524178
B  2.762190 -0.443031
C  0.867519  0.078460
```

or you can **pass list of functions** as `aggfunc` parameter and then reindex:

```
>>> df3 = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D','E'], rows=['B'], aggfunc=[np.sum, np.mean])
>>> df3
        sum                mean          
          D         E         D         E
B                                        
A  1.810847 -4.193425  0.226356 -0.524178
B  2.762190 -3.544245  0.345274 -0.443031
C  0.867519  0.627677  0.108440  0.078460
>>> df3 = df3.ix[:, [('sum', 'D'), ('mean','E')]]
>>> df3.columns = ['D', 'E']
>>> df3
          D         E
B                    
A  1.810847 -0.524178
B  2.762190 -0.443031
C  0.867519  0.078460
```

Alghouth, it would be nice to have an option to defin `aggfunc` for each column individually. Don't know how it could be done, may be pass into `aggfunc` dict-like parameter, like `{'D':np.mean, 'E':np.sum}`.

**update** Actually, in your case you can **pivot by hand**:

```
>>> df.groupby('B').aggregate({'D':np.sum, 'E':np.mean})
          E         D
B                    
A -0.524178  1.810847
B -0.443031  2.762190
C  0.078460  0.867519
```

Comment: Thanks, both ways would work. however what I was hoping to get was some single step way. As you said being able to define function for each individual columns. I will wait if anyone else knows of any such way else I will accept yours as an answer in a while.

Comment: @VIKASHJAISWAL see third method, I think this is what you need

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I was looking for, infact this works for grouping by multi columns as well, df.groupby(['B','C']).aggregate({'D':np.sum, 'E':np.mean}). Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 75):

You can apply a specific function to a specific column by passing in a dict.

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D','E'], rows=['B'], aggfunc={'D':np.sum, 'E':np.mean})
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Elegant compared to the marked answer.

Comment: I agree with the answer. However, in the most recent version of pandas, the keyword argument rows has been replaced by index. Running
`pd.pivot_table(df, values=['D','E'], index=['B'], aggfunc={'D':np.sum, 'E':np.mean})`
worked for me.

Comment: @PhilipEgger Could you share what worked with the new pandas version? That would help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
table = pivot_table(df, values=['D', 'E'], index=['A', 'C'],
                aggfunc={'D': np.mean,'E': np.sum})
```

> > > table
> > >                         D         E
> > >                      mean      sum
> > >       A   C
> > >       bar large  5.500000  7.500000
> > >           small  5.500000  8.500000
> > >       foo large  2.000000  4.500000
> > >           small  2.333333  4.333333